# Knockout cascading List from same source

Tags: drop-down-menu, knockout.js, cascadingdropdown

I need to present 5 dropdown lists in my UI, populated with a Knockout ObservableArray.
All 5 read from the same source ko.observableArray([]).

I have two problems:

1. How do I make each option only become active after the option before it has been selected? Should only have the first dropdown active, once a selection has been made then activate teh second one, until user has selected all 5.
2. Each dropdown is reading from the same observableArray, but I don't want users to be able to select the same option as prior the dropdowns. How do I make the second dropdown show all options excluding what as picked in the first dropdown? How do I make the third dropdown show all optoins excluding what was selected in the first and second dropdown?
   I can do cascading dropdowns from loading from different sources, but I don't really want to have to make 5 separate $.getJSON calls, I'd much prefer one at the initial pageLoad.

I've found a few prior questions on cascading select lists, but not for reading from the same one source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `enable` binding to connect the previous select `value` with the second select.

So when you select something in the first dropwdown the `firstValue` will contain the selected value so the `enable: firstValue` will be true and it will enable the second dropdown

```
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'value', 
                   optionsCaption: '', value: firstValue"></select>
<select data-bind="options: secondOptions, optionsText: 'value', 
                   optionsCaption: '',value: secondValue, 
                   enable: firstValue"></select>
```

To solve the "cascading" you can use computed properties to fill in the options with filtering out the already selected values:

```
var VM = function () {

    this.options = ko.observableArray(/* load your original options here */);

    this.firstValue = ko.observable();
    this.secondValue = ko.observable();

    this.secondOptions = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.options(), function (item) {
            return item != firstValue();
        });
    }, this);
}
```

And apply these patterns for the other 3 dropdowns.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR6FM/).